# How to track which record failed while using Hibernate bulk save using collections

Tags: java, hibernate, bulkinsert

We are using Hibernate bulk update> we do it by creating a collection of objects and performing a save using the collection which in-turn will update or create bulk records in the table.
Our question is if the save fails due to any exception, all the records are rolled back. is there any chance to get which record caused the exception?
So that we can skip the problematic record and proceed with other record updates?

Comment: In general this shows problem of your application logic: it produces entities for storage, which are not persistable/savable.   If you are unable to redesign the logic, I would suggest introduce validation for your entities. And in bulk processing filter-out entities in your collection which don't pass validation.

Comment: Thanks llya.. but my question is if anything fails due to SQL exception, how can i know which item in the collection has caused and in that case, can i skip that and run the remaining ?

Comment: than you can't do this in bulk: run row by row save in separate transactions, and you will see which transactions failed (if you would log each request), and why, and all the rest will be stored. However, this will reduce the throughput of the system: there will be no use of bulk sql capabilities, available in hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for the response llya !! :)

Comment: is there any other technology which will help me to perform the operation and also track the failures?

Comment: there are lots of possibilities. in general it depends on your stack and how you can customize/tighten hibernate: for example you can introduce custom insert statement , which will try to do upsert (not every db supports this). Or you can introduce the sql function which will try to do insert, and in case of problems will insert into error-logging table, and reuse that function in the custom insert statement.

Comment: Thanks llya.. the problem here is client doesnt what their login to be in database ... so cant really use procs or functions in database :(